# How can i make a auto accept in phing?

Tags: php, deployment, console, phing

I'm using phing for deployment.

One of my target build as test version:

```
    <exec command="php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force" dir=""/>
    <exec command="php app/console doctrine:schema:create" dir=""/>
    <exec command="php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load" dir="" passthru="true"/>
```

The last command requires a "y" to run. How can i tell phing that it should automatically assume a "y" if prompted?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `yes` linux command. Modify your last line to:

```
<exec command="yes | php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load" dir="" passthru="true"/>
```

More info: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/yes.htm

Comment: If I resolve your problem, please consider accepting the answer.